# Why my Rewrite Rule causing Error 400 for all ajax?

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a geoip http header named {HTTP:CF-IPCountry} that store the country code like FR, US etc.. what i need to do is to add this query string loc={HTTP:CF-IPCountry} to the website homepage https://example.com/test-website/ and to any page that has url start with https://example.com/test-website/products/ and append the query string if there are any other query strings used on the url so if the user requested page https://example.com/test-website/products/shoe/?size=s it should rewrited as https://example.com/test-website/products/shoe/?size=s&loc=us

This is how htaccess file looks like curently

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test-website/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test-website/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loc [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%{REQUEST_URI}/?loc=%{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} [NC,NE,R,L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

my last rewriterule has 2 issues which i whish to solve
1- Its causing a 400 error for all ajax on my website on both frontend and wordpress admin panel

2- I wanna apply that rewriteRule to 2 places, at the moment that rule works only on the homepage and on https://example.com/test-website/wp-admin/
Those 2 places i wanna apply to are...
a- To the website homepage https://example.com/test-website/
b- To all pages that start with https://example.com/test-website/products/

Thanks

Comment: Add another RewriteCond to exempt POST requests or the AJAX target from redirects.

Comment: @mario sorry but how can i do that, i'm totally new to regex and htaccess rewrite rules,i barely just started learning php :)

Comment: Then perhaps leave the RewriteRules be in the meantime. The header is already available in PHP as `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]` anyway.

Comment: @mario Thanks mario, i know, actually i had to do it with rewite to avoid page caching... my goal is to display different woocommerce pricing based on country but this wont work properly if page caching is working but anyway i found the solusion to exclude the post or the ajax url from rewrite which works nicely.... 

However i still have issue with setting the rewrite for specific pages as i mentioned on #2 on my main question

Comment: That's not really a second part question, but a second question. And I feel like the description is too coarse. A rewrite log might entice someone to answer it perhaps.

Comment: yeah i see your point, i will create a new question then